# SQL Replace any number with new number

Tags: sql

I have a column in a table which displays the quantity of a product.  I'd like to change all of these to "0"

I have tried the replace command but not sure how to set it so it changes all entries in the column to 0

```
    UPDATE `oc_preorder_products` 
    SET `preorder_quantity` = replace(preorder_quantity, 'ANY NUMBER IN COLUMN', '0')
```

Comment: Which RDMS are you using?

Comment: Why don't you simply ` UPDATE oc_preorder_products SET preorder_quantity =0` ?

Comment: You're using 'string literals' - surely a *quantity* is an integer not a string.?

Answer (score 1):

in mysql 8.x you can use

REGEXP_REPLACE

```
UPDATE `oc_preorder_products` 
    SET `preorder_quantity` = 
REGEXP_REPLACE(preorder_quantity, '[1-9]', '0')
```

in older versions you can use for example https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp  or nest all REPLACE(REPLACE)preorder_quantity,'2',0),'1',0) and so on

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, thank you tinazmu

```
UPDATE oc_preorder_products SET preorder_quantity =0
```